# Is there a method in Python to expand a coordinate to a white border?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

is there an algortihmus that determines a direction vector from the center of a coordinate (x,y) and then moves this pixel in this direction until it meets a white pixel? Here is an example image:
[image]
from the blue line the pixels should move in the direction of the red arrows. My idea would be to determine the direction vector of the pixel and the center point and then move it until it hits a white pixel.

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - and provide minimal data and code samples for people to work with

Comment: smells like some type of "active shape" model. -- anyway, surely you can program that? just scan perpendicular to the contour on every contour point, see which way you need to walk, then move the point.

Comment: Take a look at `cv.convexHull`, [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html). For the case shown it makes what you want.

Comment: I had the same problem, `dlib` shape predictor works good enough and easy to train.

Comment: @Hihikomori Maybe i can use a simple blob detection? Or do you think it wont work?